# React setState with dynamic key and object value not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, immutability, setstate

i'm facing an issue with react's method (setState), hope you can help.

I have a handleChange method using dynamic keys to 'persist' data in the state.. i looks like this:

```
handleChange = (event, group) => {
  event.persist(); //Used to avoid event recycling.
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [group]: { ...prevState[group], [event.target.name]: event.target.value }
    }),
    () => console.log("state", this.state)
  );
};
```

this method works pretty well when theres just one 'instance' of my custom component using the mentioned handleChange method. The problem began when i wanted to have several components using that method, because when called, its overriding the prevState value. For example:

Initial state: `{mockedValue:'Im here to stay'}`

then i call handleChange for group 'alpha', to add to this values `{name:a}`,

Next state: `{alpha:{name:a},mockedValue:'Im here to stay'}`

then i call handleChange for group 'beta', to add to this values  `{otherName:b}`,

expected state: `{alpha:{name:a}, beta:{otherName:b},mockedValue:'Im here to stay'}`

Next state : `beta:{otherName:b},mockedValue:'Im here to stay'}`

Not sure why this is happening, perhaps i'm misunderstanding some concept, the fact is that i don't have idea why this is not working as expect, (perhaps it's because computed name value, but not sure..) Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks for reading! :)

**Update**
Code in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/v3ok1jx175

**Update2: SOLVED**

Thanks for your support **Thollen** and **DevSerkan**, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you include your entire component so we can see how you are using this method? It might be useful to see how you are using the component in other components as well, because there is nothing wrong with the method itself. It might be worth writing `const { name, value } = event.target;` and use that instead and remove `event.persist();`, but I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: In your app are `event.target.name` values like `a` and `b`? In your code it seems so, but in the explanation it seems you are setting the state together with { a:1, b:2 } in one time?

Comment: It is better to use https://codesandbox.io Also, your code seems not right. You mixed some parts. Also, `ChildComponent` seems it is waiting some props like `name`, `state` and `defaultValue` but you are not passing it from the parent. Additionally, where is `group` defined in your parent component?

Comment: You're right devserkan, i just uploaded the complete version to codesandbox (i was trying to focus on handleChange method on fiddle).. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Gf7 Great that you figured it out. Consider removing the answer from your question and post it as an answer below instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i had the handleChange event at the wrong level... it means that i was defining the handleChange method inside the child Componet, for instance:

```
    class Parent extends React.Component {
      render(){
        return( 
           <div>
             <Child/>
             <Child/>
             <Child/>
           </div>
    );
   }
}
```

so there was just one 'instance' of handleChange method shared by all the 'instances' , it's a wrong approach. to solve this, i modified Parent like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
       handleChange(){
       //updateState Operations here...
      }             
          render(){
            return( 
               <div>
                 <Child handleChange = {this.handleChange}/>
                 <Child handleChange = {this.handleChange}/>
                 <Child handleChange = {this.handleChange}/>
               </div>
           );
       }
    }
```

in this way, i removed the responsibility of handling change from the 'top level child' to the parent, where the child components were being used.